# Nested control event firing programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a strange problem and am not sure how to solve it. I have 3 wpf user controls. Say GroupHolder, Group and Child. Child is a small user control and its parent is Group. GroupHolder is the parent of Group.

Diagrammatic control structure.

```
Groupholder
    |
    |
  Group
    |
    |
 |---------|----------------|
Child     Child           Child
```

I am adding all these controls programmatically. My problem is I have to route the click event fired in Child to GroupHolder.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. I think currently 'bubbling routed event' is better for my situation :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply define the event as a *bubbling* routed event and handle it at any level of the tree. For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx